# Rounded Corners in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I'm having a bit of difficulty getting rounded corners to work in internet explorer 8. I've been trying to use a [jQuery plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/) to make it work, but there is an issue. This plugin only works if the div has a background color. What I'm trying to do is give rounded corners to a div that is a white square with a blue border. I want the blue border to be rounded, similar to the way `border-radius` works. If anyone has any suggestions on making this work, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: It's not worth it for the simple reason that IE8 users aren't used to seeing rounded corners these days anyway since it isn't supported. People stopped using plugins for it a long time ago.

Comment: Do you really have a lot of IE8 users?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) for this.

> PIE makes Internet Explorer 6-9 capable of rendering several of the
>   most useful CSS3 decoration features.

Answer (score 0):

Border radius is not supported by Internet Explorer 8 - as per http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius

You can download a polyfill such as [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/) which will allow you to use CSS3 on older browsers you can see a border-radius demo [here](http://css3pie.com/demos/border-radius/)